# Overloading operator+ in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I have a little problem with one of my task for exercise for exam. This is a text:

> Class MyFloat have a private variable float num. You have to write methods which will enable next lines of code:
>       MyFloat x = 3.5;
>       MyFloat y = x + 3.2
>       float z = 3.4 + y

And I write this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class MyFloat
{
    float num;
public:
    MyFloat(float n)
    {
        num = n;

    }
    MyFloat operator+(MyFloat x)
    {
        float result;
        result = x.num + this->num;
        return result;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    MyFloat x = 3.75;
    MyFloat y = x + 3.2;
    float z = 3.4 + y;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I get error in this line:

```
float z = 3.4 + y;
```

It says:

> error C2677: binary '+' : no global operator found which takes type 'MyFloat' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

What should I do? How to solve this problem???

Comment: You need to make `+` non-member function.

Comment: You can make a non-member operator overload

Comment: It's been awhile since I've done operator overloading in C++, but couldn't he just do `MyFloat operator+ (float x) { return num + x; }`? He's adding a native `float` to a `MyFloat` instance.

Comment: @crush, if he did this he could make y + 3.4 but not 3.4 + y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a solution:

```
class MyFloat
{
    float num;
public:
    MyFloat(float n)
    {
        num = n;
    }

    operator float() const {
        return num;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyFloat x = 3.75;
    MyFloat y = x + 3.2f;
    float z = 3.4f + y;
}
```

Initially, I also though about making `MyFloat operator+(MyFloat, MyFloat)` a non-member friend function but it still doesn't make the line

`float z = 3.4 + y;`

to compile. The reason is that `3.4 + y` will be of type `MyFloat` and therefore you can't assign it to `float z` unless you provide a converting operator from `MyFloat` to `float`. Buth then, `3.4f + y` becomes ambiguous (at least for VS 2010) because it can either call `MyFloat operator+(MyFloat, MyFloat)` or it can convert `y` to `float` and use the built-in operator `+` for `float`s.

Comment: This works (which is why I upvoted the answer), but I think it's important to note that there are cases you wouldn't want to do this.  For instance, if `MyFloat` had a larger range than `float`  ( http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/ ), converting a `MyFloat` instance to a `float` would cause you to lose that advantage.

Comment: It is a good idea to use conversion.. just be careful when you use it sometimes...

Comment: @MaxLybbert. I agree that conversions might be problematic. However the OP states that `MyFloat` is a wrapper to a `float` so, in this case, the conversion doesn't loose information. Having said that, see my next comment to v0idmp3.

Comment: @v0idmp3: Although this is a correct solution for the exact problem that you posted, MaxLybbert has a good point (see his comment) about conversions. In addition, I bet your teacher is expecting a solution more similar to that of [texasbruce](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18641433/1137388)'s. So, you'd better take his.

Comment: This is a valid answer in some cases.  It's just important to know when it works, and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Implement `operator+` as non-member friend function with 2 arguments `MyFloat operator+(MyFloat x, MyFloat y)`.

Why doesn't it work in the current version? Because member operator functions are called on the objects on the left side of the operator. In your case on the left side you have integer literal which is not an object so lacks `MyFloat operator+(MyFloat x)` member function.

Non-member variants of operators are symmetrical and do not require the left side  being an object. Symmetricity is important because as you see in your example `operator+` is not symmetrical as we are used to think in math

---

**Edit**: But this is still not enough as noted by Cassio Neri in comments. Why? See his answer for the explanation but in short: you have ambiguity problems. You can use either his solution or this one if you do manual casting like this: `float z = 3.4f + static_cast<float>(y);` which is quite ugly. You can use another cast: `float z = MyFloat(3.4f) + y` if you provide `MyFloat::operator float` conversion.

Another solution to solve the same ambiguity problem: In C++11 you could use your own suffix literal (similar to `f` prefix for built-in floats, for example `3.4_f`; (underscore means that this suffix literal is user-defined). Sample implementation (given that you implement operators for casting from `MyFloat` to `float` and backwards:

```
MyFloat operator "" _f(long double val) {
    return MyFloat(static_cast<float>(val)); }

int main() {
    MyFloat x = 3.75;
    MyFloat y = x + 3.2;
    float z = 3.4_f + y; 
}
```

Comment: Good intention but it doesn't make the line `float z = 3.4 + y;` to compile. See why in my post.

Comment: My main point was the fact that `MyFloat operator+(MyFloat, MyFloat)` returns a `MyFloat`. Hence, the expression `3.4 + y` has type `MyFloat`. Therefore, it cannot be assigned to a `float` (in `float z = 3.4 + y`) unless there's a converting operator from `MyFloat` to `float`. It's true that `3.4` is a `double` literal and when it's assigned to a `float` the compiler yields a (rather annoying) warning but this is still legal code.

Comment: Why is there an `int` in your sample prototype?

Comment: @MooingDuck, that's a silly mistake I fixed in one of my edits and that roll-backed by copy-pasting a part of the old answer

Answer (score 3):

You only have **MyFloat + float** operation, and you need to define **float + MyFloat** operation too. They are not the same.

Add this to your public functions:

```
friend float operator+ (const float& lhs, const MyFloat& rhs);
```

And this outside the class:

```
float operator+ (const float& lhs, const MyFloat& rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs.num;
}
```

---

**Note:** Edited as per comment by CassioNeri.

Comment: Almost! The only problem is taking the arguments by reference which  cannot bind to rvalues. Take either by value or by reference-to-const.

Comment: Then +1 for your post.

Answer (score 0):

While you can proceed with the answer where you define the "cast to float" approach, I believe it is better for your own sake that you start making use of your public API to implement additional behavior.

In general, a simple "casting" will not do the trick (for example, what happens if `MyFloat` were `MyMatrix`?).

The approach below is certainly more verbose, but it stresses that you should "eat your own food", meaning that you should try to implement additional behavior based on your own public interface, rather than a bunch of obscure implicit casts, or `friend` functions. If you use your own API: You will understand its limitations, and may potentially save recompilation of the main class if you make modifications.

Also, suppose that you wanted to count the accesses to your class (or otherwise control access to the underlying value): using the casting operator you would need to duplicate the code in `operator float()` and in `float value()`.

So, here is my humble suggestion which appears longer but, to my taste, better reflects OO design principles.

```
#include<iostream>

class MyFloat {

 public:
  MyFloat(float value):
      m_value(value) { }

  float value() const {
    return m_value;
  }

 private:
  float m_value;

};

// Eat your own food: implement functions using your public interface
// until proven need to do otherwise. This will help you assess the
// usability of your API.
float operator+(const MyFloat& lhs, const MyFloat& rhs) { return lhs.value() + rhs.value(); }
float operator+(const MyFloat& lhs, float rhs) { return lhs.value() + rhs; }
float operator+(float lhs, const MyFloat& rhs) { return lhs + rhs.value(); }

// See, now I can define another operator without need to recompile my
// class (this could have been placed in another file)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyFloat& mf) {
  os<<"MyFloat("<<mf.value()<<")";
  return os;
}

int main() {

  MyFloat x = 3.5;      // would not work if I had declared the constructor as "explicit"
  MyFloat y = x + 3.2;
  MyFloat z = 3.4 + y;

  std::cout<<x<<", "<<y<<", "<<z<<std::endl;
}
```

Output (compiled with `g++ example.cpp -Wall -Wextra`):

```
MyFloat(3.5), MyFloat(6.7), MyFloat(10.1)
```